# Regexp Filter Boost

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to boost hits based on a regexp. For example, searching through records with user's names, I'd like to boost those that start with the query. I've tried a query like the following but it doesn't work like I'd like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "boost_factor": 2,
          "filter": {
            "regexp": {
              "name_not_analyzed": "^frank.*"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "frank",
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "site_id": {
                  "term": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to give me the results I want:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "frank",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "site_id": {
              "term": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": {
              "query": "frank",
              "max_expansions": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

when using the analyzer as explained at http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching/